# Overcoming layer limit on OSX

Tags: qgis, vector, osx

I am trying to add many layers to a project in QGIS. After adding approximately 80 layers, QGIS returns this error: "not a valid or recognized data source". There is nothing wrong with the shapefiles themselves, they will all open if done individually. It seems to just be after a certain number that it won't allow any more. The error message seems strange to me.

Is there a limit to the number of layers a single project can have?

Comment: Looks like this might be an OSX problem? Does anybody know if there is a solution to this? http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4013

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: This issue has been addressed with [the following commit to QGIS master branch](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/d8e5c2f8). The fix may soon be backported to the 2.0.x branch as well.

Since the issue stems from how many files an application can have open at once on a Mac, try moving your data to a database instead.

You can import your shapefiles into [Spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org)/[PostGIS](http://postgis.net) databases (db). Spatialite is file-based and built on top of [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), allowing for easier portability and offers many advantages over shapefiles. You could import all of your shapefiles into one Spatialite db file, thereby circumventing the Mac limit.

PostgreSQL/PostGIS is more complicated but worth the investment of time and effort, and is available via [Mac installers from Kyngchaos.com](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres).

NOTE (June, 2013): Spatialite 4 offers many of the features of PostgreSQL/PostGIS and seems to be quite a bit faster than version 3, but is not currently fully functional in the [master branch of QGIS](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#421-Nightly-Builds). There is an effort to have it ready for QGIS 2.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem loading a bunch of raster files with QGIS 2.0 and Mac but using QGIS 1.8 solved the problem for me.

Comment: This issue is not a regression in version 2.0. The issue has been present in every version of QGIS up until the noted commit in my answer. If you get the "not a valid or recognized data source" error in 2.0, it may be for a different reason.

Comment: @dakcarto I'm using a project whit many raster files that works only in QGIS 1.8!

Comment: Exactly how many layers, and are any layers of the same raster file (i.e. imported multiple times)?

Comment: @dakcarto now I've uninstall QGIS 2.0 but they where 149 different raster files (average dimension 4MB, RGB or single band image) I think it stop loading them in the middle...